# How to make PostgreSQL work with OSGi using EclipseLink

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, osgi, manifest

I need to develop a OSGi bundle with EclipseLink, which should connect to PostgreSQL, but I wasted a bunch of time and could not make it work. I receive this "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named rooms".

Basically, I followed the steps of tutorials I found on the web.  I use Eclipse Indigo

```
Manifest file : 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Meta-Persistence: persistence.xml
JPA-PersistenceUnits: rooms
Bundle-ClassPath: ., META-INF/persistence.xml
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: PMSTestTask
Bundle-SymbolicName: PMSTestTask
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: pmstesttask.Activator
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Import-Package: javax.persistence;version="2.0.3", org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0", org.postgresql
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa;bundle-version="2.1.0", org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi;bundle-version="2.3.0"
```

persistence.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="rooms" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>test_task.domain.Room</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Hotel_test_task" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>
```

Activator.java

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("rooms");
 EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Update. 0

Added required-bundle to manifest. And got this

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi_2.3.0.v20110604-r9504 [26]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.persistence.core; bundle-version="2.3.0"
```

Comment: Did you try to run without <provider> tag? Provider should be initialized implicitly by EclipseLink.

Comment: yes, I've tried without <provider>, but it just didn't work out

Comment: what version of equinox do you use? I know that Equinox 3.7.0 does not work with EclipseLink 2.3.x.

Comment: Try new org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.osgi.PersistenceProvider.PersistenceProvider().createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT, emptyMap) instead of javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory  ... http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.1/org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/osgi/PersistenceProvider.html says "JPA provider for use in OSGI Environments" ... i wasted days before i've found this piece of "code"

Answer (score 1):

Since you are instantiating the EMF yourself (and not using e.g. Enterprise OSGi to get the EMF injected), you have to add the EclipseLink classes to the classpath of the bundle, otherwise Java cannot instantiate the specified `<provider>` class, which may leed to this error message.

See the [LazyLoadingRCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/OSGi/LazyLoadingRCP) example, especially the classloader notes for the `org.eclipse.persistence.example.jpa.rcp.comics` bundle, or the concrete [MANIFEST.MF](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/tags/2.3.2/examples/org.eclipse.persistence.example.jpa.rcp.comics/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF) of that bundle (the EclipseLink classes are included with `Require-Bundle`).

Comment: Thank you, I've added Require-Bundle in Manifest but it didnt help. I guess I've misconfigured Eclipse somehow. I do have all required jars in Eclipse Build Path, but I receive error like this :!ENTRY org.eclipse.persistence.jpa 4 0 2012-02-13 21:10:57.675
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa_2.3.0.v20110604-r9504 [27]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.persistence.core; bundle-version="2.3.0"

Comment: The error message is rather clear, the bundle org.eclipse.persistence.jpa cannot be started since it requires the bundle org.eclipse.persistence.core which seems to be missing in your classpath.

Comment: Yep, it is clear, but persistence.core.jar is also in classpath